# JMeter script to read values from JMeter properties file

Tags: jmeter

Can you please help in reading values from below files using JMeter Script or Beanshell script.

```
     jmeter.properties  
     user.properties
     jmeter.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "reading"? JMeter loads the properties defined in `jmeter.properties` and `user.properties` during its startup and you can get any value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

If you need to do this programmatically - here is example [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code (can be used in any of [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223))

```
def jmeter_properties = new Properties()
jmeter_properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File('jmeter.properties')))
jmeter_properties.each { property ->
    log.info(property.getValue())
}
```

`jmeter.bat` is a wrapper [Windows batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), it doesn't contain any JMeter Properties definitions